# Windows Server 2012 AVMA stops working after OS customisation

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

We have several Windows Sever 2012 R2 VMs running on Hyper-V (Windows Sever 2012 R2 Datacenter). A few of these are fairly untouched (installed OS & installed a few service applications) and these have no problems with AVMA (Automatic Virtual Machine Activation) licensing, both with entering the key and auto-renewing the activation every 7 days etc.

However there is a VM, which uses the 'Server Core' installation, which is having difficulty playing nice with AVMA. I don't have direct access to the Hyper-V server nor any other 2012 R2 server so it's difficult to test things out & get feedback. I don't believe it's possible to use AVMA from an evaluation version of 2012?

When it fails it has the following symptoms;

- If the AVMA key is installed and activated beforehand, AVMA is unable to reactivate automatically, changing the state from 'Licensed' to 'Unlicensed'. However calling 'slmgr /ato' manually does reset the 'Automatic VM activation expiration' time (from slmgr /dlv). Once 'Unlicensed' the 'ato' command is unable to get it back into a 'Licensed' state
- If the key is removed (upk/cpku/rearm/reboot), then reinstalled (ipk), then using 'slmgr /ato' reports 'Error : Product Activation Failed'.

This VM is a bit different as there is a degree of customisation. If the Server Core VM is not customised then there is no problems with AVMA, indicating the problem is caused by the customization. The customisation is performed by VB Scripts/Batch files.

Thing is, we've narrowed it down to the point where the failure appears to be caused by a handful of different commands, seemingly unrelated with licensing and if run manually or in sufficiently small groups in batch files, the AVMA continues to operate.

All the commands were run on a fresh installation of Windows Server 2012 R2 Server Core.

Installing the NetFx3 component from the setup script causes AVMA to fail, but if run manually (outside the script, from the command prompt) AVMA is okay. In addition, running from the script causes the 'Installation ID' to change according to 'slmgr /dlv', while running the command from the command line the Installation ID does not change.

```
dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /all /source:D:\sources\sxs /NoRestart
```

If the following 4 batch files are run as one, AVMA fails. If run individually, then AVMA is ok.

Batch 1

```
REM Bootscreen
bcdedit /set {current} quietboot Yes
REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Background" /v OEMBackground /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
mkdir C:\WINDOWS\system32\oobe\info\backgrounds
copy "C:\Setup\Files\background.jpg" "C:\WINDOWS\system32\oobe\info\backgrounds\backgroundDefault.jpg"
REM Theme
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ThemeManager" /v ThemeActive /t REG_SZ /d "0" /f
```

Batch 2

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Accessibility\HighContrast" /v Flags /t REG_SZ /d "127" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Accessibility\HighContrast" /v "High Contrast Scheme" /t REG_SZ /d "High Contrast White" /f
```

Batch 3

```
regedit /s C:\Setup\Files\Colours.reg

REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v FontSmoothing /t REG_SZ /d "2" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v FontSmoothingType /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
```

Batch 4

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects" /v VisualFXSetting /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics" /v ScrollHeight /t REG_SZ /d "-360" /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics" /v ScrollWidth /t REG_SZ /d "-360" /f
```

This will also cause AVMA to fail.

```
takeown /f C:\Windows\Branding /r /d y  
takeown /f "C:\Windows\Branding\ShellBrd\shellbrd.dll"
icacls "C:\Windows\Branding\ShellBrd\shellbrd.dll" /grant Everyone:(F)
del "C:\Windows\Branding\ShellBrd\shellbrd.dll" 
takeown /f "C:\Windows\Branding\basebrd\basebrd.dll"
icacls "C:\Windows\Branding\basebrd\basebrd.dll" /grant Everyone:(F)
del "C:\Windows\Branding\basebrd\basebrd.dll"
```

Comment: Do you have access to MS? THis is one thing I would take up with their PSS - Professional Support Services. Because it seriously smells like a bug (so the PSS ticket will be free) and MS seems to be in the need of fixing this (which we can not do here).

Comment: Not directly, but we'll ask what support is available via those who acquired the Windows Datacenter licenses. I've also asked the question on the Microsoft technet forum as well FWIW.

Comment: I really would take this up with PSS. Seriously. Because if that is a bug (and it looks like) then there I could demand a hotfix ;)